# singly linked list infinite loop when inserting an element at the end python

Tags: python

When I want to add an element at the end of my linked list it result in an infinite loop, here's the method i used

```
#insert at the end of the list

def append(self, data=None):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
    itr = self.head
    while itr.next:
        itr.next = new_node
        itr = itr.next
```

Comment: do you want to add a single element or n numbers?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Matiiss the OP is trying to implement a linked list.

Comment: @Sırrı Kırımlıoğlu I want to add n elements

Comment: Your loop is adding nodes infinitely to the end and looping through them.

Comment: It looks like your `Node` constructor does not set its `next` to something false-y.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should return after adding the new node at the head if the list is empty.

After that your while loop is an infinite loop

You need to update it's position BEFORE you add to it and then add to it outside the loop

```
def append(self, data=None):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
        return
    itr = self.head
    while itr.next:
        itr = itr.next
    itr.next = new_node
```

Also your Node() should have a parameter for next

Comment: thanks a lot that really helps, one more question why my code should return after adding the new node at the head if the list is empty ? and and why it return nothing?

Comment: If the list is empty, adding the node is the end of the function. There's no reason to start looping through anything. You return nothing because it requires no output. It's just ending the function. Without the return, this code will add two nodes to an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the loop:

```
while itr.next:
   itr.next = new_node
   itr = itr.next
```

When appending an item to an empty list, `itr` is initially is equal to `new_node`.
You set `itr.next` to `new_node`, so now `new_node.next` is equal to `new_node`. You have now created a cycle in your list, so it will loop forever.

When appending an item to your list, you should only be modifying the last element - the loop only serves to traverse the list to get to the end. It should look like:

```
def append(self, data=None):
    new_node = Node(data)
    if self.head is None:
        self.head = new_node
    else: 
        # you only need to traverse the list when it isn't empty
        itr = self.head
        while itr.next:
            itr = itr.next
        itr.next = new_node # only add the new node after traversing the list
```

That being said, this method of appending is `O(n)` complexity, and you can make it `O(1)` by keeping a pointer to the tail of the list and modifying the tail without traversing the list to find it.